# something wrong with my ArrayAdapter code, but I can't figure it out?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

please help me understand why my ArrayAdapter is not working properly, I mean it dosen't show the List of Strings that I gave as a parameter. I receive the flowing message in emulator"unfortunately 'program name' has stopped". but when I give a regular String [] array it show the items properly.
here is  the "problematic" code sections.

```
//this method is in Class DatabaseAccess, it return a record from db as List<String> 
public List<String> getQuestionRecord() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int counter = 1;
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast() && (counter < 8)) {
        list.add(cursor.getString(counter++));
    }
    if (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }else{
        closeCursor();
        return null;
    }
    return list;
}

// this method called from the MainActivity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
    databaseAccess.open();
    databaseAccess.getCursorReady();
    List<String> questionRecord = databaseAccess.getQuestionRecord();
    if (questionRecord != null){
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,questionRecord);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }else
        databaseAccess.close();
}
```

Comment: can you also post error log/stacktrace

Comment: Your adapter is not able to handle a `List<String>` but is able to handle a `String[]` array, so to just make it work add a conversion below `List<String> questionRecord = databaseAccess.getQuestionRecord();`, like `String[] questionRecAsArray = new String[questionRecord.size()];` and then `questionRecAsArray = questionRecord.toArray(questionRecAsArray);`. Then you add the `questionRecAsArray` to your adapter if the `questionRecord != null`

Comment: I think that the problem is with the ListView object. it seems that it can't handle long String arrays like the one I passed to the adapter. the string array contain 8 strings and each string is a fairly long sentence. I guess the ListView object is running out of space ....

Comment: I figured it out, the variable of type List<String> named questionRecord , has a null value in the last item. when I removed the null the code worked perfectly. so android ListView can't handle null String value inside an array , I don't know why is this.